# React not re-rendering a map function on redux store change ( with MaterializeCss select options)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

React not re-rendering when redux state changes.

When I enter this page, initially the redux store "Customers" is empty. It fetches the data, redux is updated, however part of the code that is not being re-rendered is the select options.., it stays with only the option of "**Loading**" despite the redux store being updated.

Here is the relevant code, simplified the best I can ..

```
class AddLoad extends Component {

render(){
           const customers = this.props.customers
return(  
    <Field>
       <option value="" disabled selected>State</option>
                {customers.length !== 0 ? (
              <option>Loading..</option>
            ) : (
              customers.map(customer => {
                return (
                  <option key={customer.id} value={customer.id}>
                    {customer.customer_name}
                  </option>
                );
              })
            )}
          </Field>
)}
}
function mapStatetoProps(state) {
  return {
    customers: state.customers.customers,
  };
}
export default reduxForm({
  form: "PostsNewForm"
})(
  connect(
    mapStatetoProps,
    { createLoad, fetchCustomers }
  )(AddLoad)
);
```

I tested this with just having a simple h1 tag in the return, and that worked fine for some reason, yet the mapping through doesn't happen again?

```
  <h1>{customers.length !== 0 ? customers[0].customer_name : "Testing"}</h1>
```

***Edit***: Besides the logic error on the customers.length ..I failed to mention I am using MaterializeCss for this select options, and in the end, the logic fix + componentDidUpdate to re-initialize Materialize fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your logic.

You have coded

`{customers.length !== 0 ? (<option>Loading..</option>`

It means that if the length is more than zero, you are rendering the Loading. It must be something like

```
render(){
const customers = this.props.customers

if(!customers.length){
 return Loading
}

return(  
    <Field>
       <option value="" disabled selected>State</option>
            customers.map(customer => {
                return (
                  <option key={customer.id} value={customer.id}>
                    {customer.customer_name}
                  </option>
                );
              })
            )}
          </Field>
     )}
```

If you want to render the loading like a field option, just change the condition. Hope to help you

Comment: I was trying so many different things, that I missed this part, thanks.